# VMPlayer 16 stopped launching on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vmware, vmware-player

I have been using VMplayer for years but it now does not launch.  APT is fully up-to-date with Ubuntu 20.04.  And I've uninstalled VMplayer and reinstalled the last version (VMplayer 16.2.3)

When I try to launch vmplayer from terminal it gives only this output (then just does nothing):

```
/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmplayer: Relink '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0' with '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6' for IFUNC symbol 'sin'
```

The only log file that I can find that is being generated it in `/tmp/vmware-username/vmware-apploader-****.log`  But it does not seem to show anything useful (see below).  **Does anyone have any ideas how to debug this?**

```
2022-05-05T10:12:39.143Z In(05) appLoader The host is 64-bit.
2022-05-05T10:12:39.143Z In(05) appLoader Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2022-05-05T10:12:39.143Z In(05) appLoader Host is Linux 5.4.0-109-generic Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS Ubuntu 20.04
2022-05-05T10:12:39.143Z In(05) appLoader Host offset from UTC is +01:00.
2022-05-05T10:12:39.291Z In(05) appLoader Invocation: "/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmplayer
2022-05-05T10:12:39.291Z In(05) appLoader "
2022-05-05T10:12:39.291Z In(05) appLoader Calling: "/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmplayer
2022-05-05T10:12:39.291Z In(05) appLoader "
2022-05-05T10:12:39.291Z In(05) appLoader VMDEVEL not set.
2022-05-05T10:12:39.291Z In(05) appLoader Using configuration file: /etc/vmware/config
2022-05-05T10:12:39.291Z In(05) appLoader Use library directory: /usr/lib/vmware
2022-05-05T10:12:39.330Z In(05) appLoader Setup root library: /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so
2022-05-05T10:12:39.330Z In(05) appLoader Execute ldd(1) in child process 20621.
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05) appLoader Initial check: (15629)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda2722000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b56d9d000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b56d3d000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libglibmm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f5b56cab000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libsigc-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigc-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b56ca2000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libatkmm-1.6.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatkmm-1.6.so.1 (0x00007f5b56c50000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f5b5649f000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f5b5639a000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgdkmm-3.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdkmm-3.0.so.1 (0x00007f5b5633d000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgtkmm-3.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1 (0x00007f5b55d9c000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f5b55c5f000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libbasichttp.so => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libbasichttp.so/libbasichttp.so (0x00007f5b55a55000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgvmomi.so => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libgvmomi.so/libgvmomi.so (0x00007f5b550b2000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libvmwarebase.so => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwarebase.so/libvmwarebase.so (0x00007f5b545b1000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libvmwareui.so => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so (0x00007f5b527cb000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5b525e7000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5b52498000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5b5247d000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5b5245a000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5b52268000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f5b521f6000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libffi.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f5b521e8000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b521e2000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5b57256000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b521b8000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b521a6000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f5b52194000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f5b5218a000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f5b5217e000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f5b5205b000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b52033000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b51ffc000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libepoxy.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f5b51ec9000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libfribidi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f5b51eaa000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b51cc9000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b51cb0000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f5b51c61000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f5b51b5c000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f5b51b15000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f5b51a54000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f5b51a4f000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f5b51a42000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f5b51a35000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f5b51a30000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f5b51a2b000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f5b519e7000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f5b519dc000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f5b519d7000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f5b519c6000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f5b519b1000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5b519a7000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgiomm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f5b517c2000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libcairomm-1.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairomm-1.0.so.1 (0x00007f5b51798000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libpangomm-1.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangomm-1.4.so.1 (0x00007f5b51766000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f5b5173c000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5b51736000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libcurl.so.4/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f5b514bd000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f5b51305000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f5b512cd000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libssl.so.1.1/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f5b51039000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f5b50b46000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5b50b2a000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libcds.so => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libcds.so/libcds.so (0x00007f5b508f2000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgcr-ui-3.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcr-ui-3.so.1 (0x00007f5b50880000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgcr-base-3.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcr-base-3.so.1 (0x00007f5b507dc000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f5b507d6000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f5b5072d000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f5b50728000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f5b50719000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f5b5050f000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f5b504be000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libatspi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f5b50487000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f5b50425000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f5b503fa000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f5b503de000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f5b503d3000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f5b503a6000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f5b50376000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f5b5036d000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f5b50365000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libicuuc.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66 (0x00007f5b5017f000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f5b50156000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgck-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgck-1.so.0 (0x00007f5b5011a000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f5b4ffe4000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f5b4fec6000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f5b4fe17000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f5b4fdc0000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f5b4fd2b000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f5b4fd21000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f5b4fd07000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libicudata.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66 (0x00007f5b4e246000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f5b4e223000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader  liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f5b4e200000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib10spawn_syncERKSsRKNS_11ArrayHandleISsNS_17Container_Helpers10TypeTraitsISsEEEENS_10SpawnFlagsERKN4sigc4slotIvNSA_3nilESC_SC_SC_SC_SC_SC_EEPSsSG_Pi    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK3Gdk11DragContext12list_targetsEv  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK3Gtk13SelectionData13get_selectionEv   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib17file_get_contentsERKSs   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustring5beginEv   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib18filename_from_utf8ERKNS_7ustringE    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK4Glib7ustring3endEv    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib11shell_quoteERKSs (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib9file_testERKSsNS_8FileTestE   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gdk6Pixbuf4saveERKSsRKN4Glib7ustringE  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK3Gtk13SelectionData10get_targetEv  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK3Gio7AppInfo14get_executableEv (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib6ModuleC1ERKSsNS_11ModuleFlagsE    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib17uri_escape_stringERKSsS1_b   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustring3endEv (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gdk6Pixbuf16create_from_fileERKSsiib   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib12get_home_dirEv   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK3Gtk13SelectionData11get_targetsEv (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib22spawn_async_with_pipesERKSsRKNS_11ArrayHandleISsNS_17Container_Helpers10TypeTraitsISsEEEENS_10SpawnFlagsERKN4sigc4slotIvNSA_3nilESC_SC_SC_SC_SC_SC_EEPiSG_SG_SG_ (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib10ObjectBase4gobjEv    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib3DirC1ERKSs    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK4Glib11DirIteratordeEv (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib15filename_to_uriERKSs (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gtk13SelectionData3setERKSsS2_ (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK4Glib10ObjectBase4gobjEv   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib8Checksum16compute_checksumENS0_12ChecksumTypeERKSs    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib17get_user_data_dirEv  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib20find_program_in_pathERKSs    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gio7AppInfo22launch_default_for_uriERKSs   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK4Glib7ustring5beginEv  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib14build_filenameERKSsS1_   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib13get_user_nameEv  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib19uri_unescape_stringERKSsS1_  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib14build_filenameERKNS_11ArrayHandleISsNS_17Container_Helpers10TypeTraitsISsEEEE    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib11spawn_asyncERKSsRKNS_11ArrayHandleISsNS_17Container_Helpers10TypeTraitsISsEEEENS_10SpawnFlagsERKN4sigc4slotIvNSA_3nilESC_SC_SC_SC_SC_SC_EEPi (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gio7AppInfo20get_default_for_typeERKSsb    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK3Gtk13SelectionData18get_data_as_stringEv  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringC1ERKSs    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustring5eraseENS_16ustring_IteratorIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPcSsEEEES6_    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK3Gtk13SelectionData13get_data_typeEv   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustring6insertENS_16ustring_IteratorIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPcSsEEEEj (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib16path_get_dirnameERKSs    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib9IOChannel12set_encodingERKSs  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib9IOChannel16create_from_fileERKSsS2_   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gtk11FileChooser12set_filenameERKSs    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib15filename_to_uriERKSsRKNS_7ustringE   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gtk11CssProvider14load_from_dataERKSs  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib16filename_to_utf8ERKSs    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK3Gtk11FileChooser18get_current_folderEv    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN5Cairo12ImageSurface15create_from_pngESs    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustring5eraseENS_16ustring_IteratorIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPcSsEEEE   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib14build_filenameERKSsS1_S1_    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib15get_current_dirEv    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gtk11FileChooser18set_current_folderERKSs  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK3Gtk11FileChooser12get_filenameEv  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gdk6Pixbuf16create_from_fileERKSs  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib11get_prgnameEv    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringaSERKSs    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib6getenvERKSs   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib29get_unichar_from_std_iteratorEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEE (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib9file_testERKSsNS_8FileTestE   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib12get_home_dirEv   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gtk11FileChooser19add_shortcut_folderERKSs (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib14build_filenameERKSsS1_   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib17path_get_basenameERKSs   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringC1ERKSs    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZNK3Gtk11FileChooser18get_current_folderEv    (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN3Gtk11FileChooser18set_current_folderERKSs  (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib6getenvERKSs   (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib29get_unichar_from_std_iteratorEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEE (/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmplayer.so/libvmplayer.so)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.427Z In(05)+ appLoader 
2022-05-05T10:12:39.428Z In(05) appLoader Use shipped C++ interface for the GTK+ library.
2022-05-05T10:12:39.429Z In(05) appLoader Execute ldd(1) in child process 20622.
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05) appLoader Setup GTKmm: (7710)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc82c64000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4e08b1f000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4e08abd000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libglibmm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f4e0884d000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libsigc-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libsigc-2.0.so.0/libsigc-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4e08647000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libatkmm-1.6.so.1 => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libatkmm-1.6.so.1/libatkmm-1.6.so.1 (0x00007f4e083fd000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f4e07c4c000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f4e07b47000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgdkmm-3.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libgdkmm-3.0.so.1/libgdkmm-3.0.so.1 (0x00007f4e07903000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgtkmm-3.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1 (0x00007f4e07244000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f4e07107000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libbasichttp.so => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libbasichttp.so/libbasichttp.so (0x00007f4e06efd000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgvmomi.so => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libgvmomi.so/libgvmomi.so (0x00007f4e0655a000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libvmwarebase.so => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwarebase.so/libvmwarebase.so (0x00007f4e05a59000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libvmwareui.so => /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libvmwareui.so/libvmwareui.so (0x00007f4e03c71000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4e03a8f000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4e03940000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader  libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4e03925000)
2022-05-05T10:12:39.518Z In(05)+ appLoader 
2022-05-05T10:12:39.519Z In(05) appLoader Check GTK+ stack in system using child process 20623.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with that version, too: VMWare tools couldn't be compiled without errors. Updating to current version 16.2.4 works without that issue.